# using a client certificate with Socket.io IOS client

Tags: ios, ssl, socket.io

I am trying to connect to a server that requires client verification. I have a .P12 certificate in the bundle within my app generated by the CA. Is there a way to get socket.IO to present this certificate when connecting to the server. (the server is a reverse proxy though I dont think this is causing a problem)

```
    let opts: [String : AnyObject] = ["log": true, "sessionDelegate": self, "forceWebsockets" : true]

    self.socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: "https://myapp.something.com:49447", options: opts)

    self.socket.on("connect") {[weak self] data, ack in
        self?.handleConnect()
        return
    }
    self.socket.connect()
```

I have a delegate setUp to handle challenges but the ssl handshake fails before I ever get to that point.

CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824 -> -9829)

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(.UseCredential, NSURLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to install the p12 by yourself into your app's keychain, refer to [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1745/_index.html)

once it installed, it will be available for the https connection.